# magento 2 extend theme only on desktop

Tags: magento2, parent-child-theme

In a child theme (luma is parent), how do I extend a desktop theme but not mobile?

something like:

if desktop "color:teal;" 
else "" <--- do nothing.

I'm using _extend.less, so far changes are applied to both mobile and regular version.